# Exception while querying the results from database?

Tags: java, oracle, spring, hibernate

I am using spring and hibernate application. i am using C3P0 connection pool to connect to oracle database. but frequently i get below the exception.

```
Database failure Exception 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:746)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:776)
```

is it something to do with C3P0 configuration? below is the c3p0 configuration:

```
<bean id="someDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
            <property name="driverClass" value="${driverClassName}" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${url}" />
            <property name="user" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />
            <!-- pool sizing -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="6" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="${common.db.max.statements}" />
        <!-- retries -->
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="1" />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" /> <!-- 1s -->

            <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select sysdate from dual" />
      </bean>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably reason for this is that you have some query which is executing so long that socket read time out occur. Can you check somehow what query is executing in moment of exception?

Answer (score 0):

There is some query that is taking too much time to return a response. The exception traces seems to be the final stack of the exception response.

If you capture the "causedBy" trace of the exception response you will be able to pin point the exact code logic which is taking huge execution time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You now have 56 reputation and are able to comment... this is more of a comment rather than an answer to a question (it's borderline)...